# C# File.exists path

Tags: c#, .net, file, c#-4.0

I have made a program that renames files in a folder, and it works, but there is one problem, if i add more files and then rename it with the program it overwrites the other files, so i have tried `if(!File.Exists)` but it keeps not working. anyone can help with the `if(!File.Exists)` part? cus this one doesn't work **and always returns true**

```
Console.WriteLine("1. Rename all\n2. Rename Custom");
int Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Clear();
if(Choice==1)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter the file path:");
   string path = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("Enter the new file type");
   string type = Console.ReadLine();
   DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@path);
   FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles("*.*");
   int i = 1;
   foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
   {
      // Do the renaming here
      if (!File.Exists(@path+i+"."+type))
         File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, "" + i + "." + type));
      i++;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need `@path`. `path` without the `@` will work just fine. Second, the file you're checking the existence of doesn't match the destination path for moving. Try this instead:

```
string destination = Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, string.Format("{0}.{1}", i, type));
if (!File.Exists(destination))
{
    File.Move(f.FullName, destination);
    i++;  // Unclear if you want this to increment every time or just when moving
}
```